# can't unassign role from user

Tags: 7, users

I am working on a site which uses someones custom module which makes some modifications on the user account page as well as his profile pages.

On this site, I registered myself as a user and logged in and found that I was assigned to all roles, even administrator. When I tried unclicking the checkboxes on the user page to unassign roles, it didn't work, the roles stayed the same. I tried this while logged in as the user himself and also as the admin.

What types of things could be causing this issue? Where should I look?

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, there are custom modules from which it is updating.

Try searching hooks like [`hook_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_insert/7) and [`hook_user_update(&$edit, $account, $category)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_update/7) from custom modules. I hope they might have written a piece of code to update the roles.